# How to convert JSON to SQLI query - php

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am pretty new to coding and I have gotten to the situation were i need to conver JSON into a SQLi Query but I am not able to accomplish what I need.

I am trying to find a way to get parameter from url and based on them use a general function to either INSER, UPDATE, DELETE or SELECT from my DataBase.

```
JSON INSERT:
{"Username":"MyEmail@email.com","Password":"329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f"}

JSON UPDATE:
{"Username":"MyEmail@email.com","Password":"newpacd392worda12123sdw112asddww"}
```

Above JSONs are retrieved from function that check URL query string and converts it to JSON

```
 function php_raw_query() {
        $raw = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $arr = array();
        $pairs = explode('&', $raw);
        foreach ($pairs as $i) {
            if (!empty($i)) {
                list($name, $value) = explode('=', $i, 2);
                if(isset($arr[$name])){
                    if (is_array($arr[$name])){
                        $arr[$name][] = $value;
                    } 
                    else {
                        $arr[$name] = array($arr[$name], $value);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    $arr[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }       
        return $arr;
    }
    $json = json_encode(php_raw_query());
```

After this is done I need to build up a variable query depending on passed data, for example if I have USER and PASS I can log in, register, request pass change or delete.

Taking this into consideration the user could execute:

`SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'Username'='MyEmail@email.com' AND 'Password'='329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f';`

Note that both the column name (Username) and Value (MyEmail@email.com) are taken from JSON Key, Value respectively and the AND statement is only included only if JSON array has more than 1 element.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: how you come to know when to insert and when to update? did you get it through url or something else.?

Comment: I call an AJAX first that uses GET method pointed the the above PHP file that will give it the SQL query to execute the update, Insert, etc could be in the url too. So the JSON can be like {"Action":"UPDATE","Username":"MyEmail@email.com","Password":"329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f"} I just need to know how to read it and build the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be helpful for you

```
$object = json_decode('{"Username":"MyEmail@email.com","Password":"329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f"}');

function generate($object) {    
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';

    $paramsArray = [];
        foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $paramsArray[] = "'$key' = '$value'";
        }

    return $query . implode(' AND ', $paramsArray) . ";";
}

echo generate($object);
```

But preparing queries this way is insecure. Look at https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

@Lukasz, I just used you piece of code and worked fine. I have applied a minimum change thoug to the raw_query func but seems to work fine.

Furthermore I did not understand the thing with SQL injections. Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Thanks.

URL: `_module.php?Username=MyEmail@email.com&Password=329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f`

`

```
ob_start();

function php_raw_query() {
    $raw = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $arr = array();
    $pairs = explode('&', $raw);
    foreach ($pairs as $i) {
        if (!empty($i)) {
            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $i, 2);
            if (isset($arr[$name])) {
                if (is_array($arr[$name])) {
                    $arr[$name][] = $value;
                } else {
                    $arr[$name] = array($arr[$name], $value);
                }
            } else {
                $arr[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($arr);
}

$object = json_decode(php_raw_query());

function generate($object) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';
    $paramsArray = [];
    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
        $paramsArray[] = "'$key' = '$value'";
    }
    return $query . implode(' AND ', $paramsArray) . ";";
}

echo generate($object);

ob_end_flush();
```

`

AJAX:

`

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {    
var information = $(this).serialize();

e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: "_module.php",
    data: information,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#post-wrapper").html(data);            
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
    }
});
```

}); 
`

The output div shows: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'username' = 'MyEmail%40email.com' AND 'password' = '329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f';`

Comment: In my piece of code change the first line to $object = json_decode('{"Username":"hej\'; DELETE FROM table; SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=MyEmail@email.com","Password":"329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f"}');

Answer (score 0):

First You decode your json code using json_decode and store in one variable and use it as in sql query.